# Extend xAxis with no point on edges in nvd3

Tags: angular, charts, nvd3.js, ng2-nvd3

I am developing charts with ng2-nvd3. Initially set xAxis range in lines:

```
            forceX: [950, 3050],
            brushExtent: [1000, 3000],
```

Providing these lines I want to filter my chart with brushExtent on xAxis and simultaneously I want to extend that area to unset first and last point of chart on edges of the area.

1.Result of use lines above:
[image]

2.Only with set brushExtent:
[image]

3.Going to achieve this result(on edges there aren't point of chart):
[image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/LP8a0oAhkIsDBYLvpKhT?p=preview